# Using YOLO: Real-Time Object Detection as a library

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, darknet

I tried YOLO [project](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) and it showed really good result. But I want to use it as a library. Like OpenCV or something. I would call some function with frame and it will give me rectangles with class types. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: There easy to use Object Detection API. It works almost as you said.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Comment: You can use one of the wrappers made by the community. This one seems ok https://github.com/for-aiur/yolo_cpp